Is it ok to use a MOSFET as a gate driver for another MOSFET?
I'm making a sound-reactive LED controller board for a friend's rock band, with entry-level knowledge of electronics.
I did a test version using the ESP32, with 12 pins directly driving AO3400A MOSFETs, which drove 12V RGB lights, with PWM at 2kHz. That's a LED light for each of the 12 channels, rated at about 50W. That fits the MOSFET specs, but still, a couple of transistors burned out at each 1h-2h show. I didn't have a heatsink but added (ground-connected) copper traces and through-holes beneath the MOSFETs to aid cooling.
Now I'm trying to design an upgraded version of the board that will drive 24V LED lights, but I'd like to avoid burning out MOSFETs.
One thing that I know I have to look for is the Vgs, which should be high enough, and with enough current provided to turn the MOSFET on completely. The "Vgs vs Id" graph for this particular MOSFET looks like the Vgs should be saturated with the 3.3V voltage from the microcontroller ports, but maybe the MCU cannot output enough current on all 12 PWM pins to do it fast enough to avoid having the MOSFET in the linear region. I don't have the equipment to measure that.
Because of this, I'm wondering if it would be a better to idea to just use 2 of the same (AO3400A) MOSFETs in series, the first turned on by the MCU with 3.3V, and it would then turn on the second MOSFET using a voltage splitter at around 10V for its Vgs.
Does that even make sense? What would be an alternative if not?
Another concern I have is that the cables to the LED lights are long-ish, 5m - 10m, but I don't know how to address problems that could arise from that (if any - the PWM frequency is in single digit kHzs).

I'm inferring that the MOSFET (AO3400A) gate is driven by 3.3V CMOS as a low-side switch.   It'd be more efficient (stay cooler) if you used higher drive voltage (like, a 10V 1k ohm Thevenin equivalent) and switched 24V at half the current to handle the "50W" light in each branch.   Is that the plan?

"... the cables to the LED lights are long-ish, 5m - 10m ..." - Do you have an oscilloscope to measure the drain voltage? I suspect induction from those long cables are causing an overshoot that violates the 30 Vdsmax of the mosfets. Seems more likely as the cause of your problems than slow switching.

@marcelm Interesting idea, I'll need to try it. I have a portable oscilloscope, should be good for that. But if so, what's the easiest solution? A TVS diode on each channel output?

@IvanVoras Good question. I think I'd try to design the system such that the FETs are closer to the LEDs. If that's impossible, I'd like a FET with a higher Vdsmax, say 60V at least? Depending on situation, a BJT instead may do the trick, I think those are more forgiving. A TVS diode may help, or maybe a small capacitor + inline resistance to dampen the spikes. I'd have to research more about that. And that's assuming I'm right ;)

Yes, or using other transistors like BJTs (or JFETs, I'm sure).
However, I don't understand exactly what you mean by MOSFETs "in series", which they almost certainly shouldn't be. They're more like cascade.
It's a fun exercise, but to do it well is not trivial.
Look at this Toshiba app-note, section 2.3
https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20180726_AKX00068.pdf?did=59460
Here's the relevant snip:

Google "discrete MOSFET driving circuits" for a lifetime's worth of papers, app notes, blog posts, etc.
Alternatively, you can buy MOSFET driver ICs, there's tons of them; e.g. ancient ICL7667 has 2 channels.
By the way, try just running it at 1 kHz (or 500 Hz) instead of 2 kHz. It should be half the switching losses (not half the total power). Maybe that's easier; and if your MOSFETs are still blowing up you can consider a sturdier driver. In a stationary application (i.e., these LEDs aren't on a bicycle wheel) nobody will see the flicker. Your camera/video might, but that's true at 2 kHz too.

You're right, "series" isn't a good word for that. Thanks for the pointers!

I think I get why the two-MOSFETs idea is tricky. I've looked at ICL7667, and 2 problems: 1) it looks like it needs 4.5V at input, and I have only 3.3V, and b) my PCBA (JLCPCB) doesn't have it. Do you know of another part I could search for? I've also looked at level translators (https://jlcpcb.com/parts/2nd/Logic/Translators_Level_Shifters_82576?spm=search&searchTxt=level%20translator) but those are capped at around 5.5V - 6V on the output.

@IvanVoras If you just need a gate driver, they're very widely available. There are a lot of good options from TI, Infineon, and Maxim, as well as a few from IXYS.

@IvanVoras Look again in the datasheet for the ICL7667, it states it needs at least 2V at the input for it to read the input as a logic 1, no matter if that chip is driven from 4.5 or 17V. It is designed with TTL logic levels in mind

I found a gate driver that looks like it should work (https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1912111437_Texas-Instruments-UCC27524DR_C465729.pdf), so the whole thing should look something like this, right? https://imgur.com/a/hVuAMcE Do you have other suggestions?
